# terminal background turn gray when open in vim

Tags: vim, terminal, terminal-color

I'm using vim in zsh in wsl, playing with it's color setting.

I want to use `colorscheme solarized` for my vim, but it caused the background of terminal color to gray (open in vim by using `:ter`)

How can I avoid it?

I know that I can use `:!(command)` or `ctrl` + `a` and `fg` to use terminal while editing in vim, but I'm just curious.

[image: terminal background color turned gray]

[image: terminal background color turned normal]

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

Like many other (inexplicably) popular colorschemes, Solarized has been abandoned for a long time. One consequence is that features like `:help hl-Terminal` and `:help g:terminal_ansi_colors`, that were introduced in the meantime, are not supported.

### Your options

- Edit the colorscheme directly.
- Override it with an autocommand, as per [this gist](https://gist.github.com/romainl/379904f91fa40533175dfaec4c833f2f).
- Find an up-to-date fork.
- Find another, well maintained, colorscheme.